# Android DialogFragment is blank

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem with creating a dialog. It does appear, but its empty inside, just a blank box is shown.

Dialog class:

```
public class SomeDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout, null));

    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

In an activity, creating an object and calling show method:

```
SomeDialog obj = new SomeDialog();
obj.show(getFragmentManager(), "randomtag");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
```

You are returning the parent method. You should return your own . Change to :

```
 return builder.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case a problem was in

```
public static DialogFragment newInstance(int param) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(EXTRA_PARAM, param);

    DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment(); // Here is an error.
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

An wrong line should be replaced with

```
DialogFragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment();
// Or YourDialogFragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment();
```